# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)>

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4 on Mac OSX. When trying to web scrape, I am getting this error.
I have searched links for this error but couldn't find any proper response for Python 3.4 on Mac OSX.
Can someone suggest me how to solve this error?Below is the code that I am trying.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")  
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for links in bsObj.findAll("a"):
   if 'href' in links.attrs:  
       print (links.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: I think this is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error/42334357

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)